# ng-bootstrap - ngbtooltip not working with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm new to angular 4 and bootstrap beta 2 and trying to use `ngbtooltip` to show tool tip text. Tooltip on the label is working fine when only input does not have `[(ngModel)]`. As soon as I used `[(ngModel)]` in input text control, tooltip is showing only for the first label and other labels does not. 
In the below code, if I remove `ngModel`, all labels tooltips are shown as expected.

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12  container accordion" id="accordion">
    <div id="collapseDealSummary" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12  card-block collapse show row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 card-body row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group pull-left mx-0 px-1" placement="top" triggers="hover" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on for label 1">
                <label>label 1<span>*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtid" name="txtid" [(ngModel)]="Label1Value" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group pull-left mx-0 px-1" placement="top" triggers="hover" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on for label 2">
                <label>label 2<span>*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group pull-left mx-0 px-1">
                <label placement="top" triggers="hover" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on for label 3">label 3<span>*</span></label>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group pull-left mx-0 px-1">
                <label placement="top" triggers="hover" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on for label 4">rlabel 4<span>*</span></label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why tooltip is not working correctly along with `[(ngModel)]`? 
Thanks

Comment: This is related to [ng-bootstrap]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent">My button</button>
```

The model variable has to be linked to [ngbTooltip].